# Spark taking long time to save pySpark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created multiple DataFrames by comparing 2 HIVE tables and storing the results back to HIVE. But while saving the DataFrame it is taking long time to get saved. I am trying to save multiple DataFrames and one of the DataFrame is having 300,000 records with around 10 variables but other DataFrames and not too large.

I have investigated further and found that each DataFrame is having 200 partitions and 35,000+ task to store the DataFrame back to HIVE.

Is their any way we can reduce the number of task while saving the DataFrame or is their any other way to optimize this task.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Neeraj

Comment: have you tried increasing the number of partitions? also what are your spark-conf settings?

Comment: it also depends on your physical memory size.Apache spark encourage 64GB standard ram for analysing big amount data but 16-32GB can also perform if you have moderate amount data for analysis

Comment: We have 512 GB of Memory on each Executor. Also, I tried number of partitions as well but no improvement. I am doing grouping aggregation and joins on my DataFrames and finally storing the DataFrame to HIVE and while saving I could see the number of tasks are very high. Is their any way to control the number of task in DataFrame API.